# How can we handle null values for Data type INTEGER while using Federated/External tables for Google Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, external-tables, federated-table

While Using below query ,i am getting the error .

bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --nullmarker="\N" --external_table_definition=/tmp/bqschema dataflowjson.TEST1
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'nullmarker'
Run 'bq help' to get help

My Date is like :
[image]

Datatype that i am giving as :
NAME:STRING,AGE:INTEGER,CITY:INTEGER

Comment: What do you mean by "handle NULL"?

Comment: I have explained the entire issue in this thread .Can you suggest.I am getting error while querying external table.

Comment: As you'd have guessed, --nullmarker is not a valid option for bq mk. Have you tried removing it? What's the result?